# Error: Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, google-earth-engine

I am with a project with React in which I want to use the library @google/earthengine, but is throwing me this error:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jxnEi.png)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8hvb.png)
This is my code that is throwing error:
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD49q.png)
Someone know how could I have localhost:3000 in authorized origins for google cloud credential? Because I have it but it isn't working:
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6vK9.png)